# Is a bootstrapped welch t test appropriate to use in non-normal distributed samples with unequal variances?

Tags: t-test, bootstrap

I want to test for an association between a continuous DV and a dichotomous IV (that has, nevertheless, an underlying continuum in it). 
However, my data are not normally distributed, so I was considering running a bootstrapped analysis. I have seen a couple of papers, however, suggesting that bootstrapping is not optimal for independent samples t test.

The group sizes are not equivalent (N=30, N=19) and homogeneity of variances was not met. So, for differences between groups on a continuous DV, I have conducted both Mann Whitney U for differences in mean ranks (U = 476, z = 3.934, p < .001 with an effect size of r = 0.562.) and Bootstrapped Welch t-test (Mean difference 18.065, BCa CIs [10.3, 25.86], t(29.411)=4.46, p=.001, an effect size of r=.635).
To me, both analysis corroborate each other, although the interpretations that can be drawn are not exactly the same for parametric and non-parametric tests. However, the effect size for bootstrapped t-test is higher.
I have also run a bootstrapped biserial correlation (rb=.73, BCa95% CIs [.403, .925], p<.001) between the variables since there is an underlying continuum in the dichotomous variable that a test for group differences ignores.
Here, however, I am a bit wary of the result since the upper BCa CI reaches r=.925 which is nearly a perfect correlation.

Which one would be a better estimate?

Answer (score 1):

I have not seen papers deprecating the use of bootstrapping
for 2-sample tests. However, among re-sampling methods, I prefer
to use a 2-sample permutation test when unsure of the normality
assumption. When also unsure of homoscedasticity, I would use
the Welch t statistic as the metric of the permutation test. [Do you have references about not using bootstrapped 2-sample t tests? I'm always happy to have my preferences backed up by facts.]

However, your comparison of the behavior of several different tests makes the point that your bootstrapped 2-sample t test does give reasonable results for your data. Questions remain whether for sample sizes 30 and 19, sample *means* are close enough to normal that a straightforward Welch would give valid results. (Of course, the usual caveat applies that one should not do several different tests for the purpose of picking the test with the smallest P-value.)

I don't have your data at hand, so I can't add a permutation test
to your list of tests for direct comparison. But I *can* show
results of a permutation test for data that may be somewhat similar to yours for purposes of illustration. (In R, `sample` without
additional parameters permutes its argument.)

```r
set.seed(2020)
x1 = round(rgamma(30, 5, .1),2)   # mean 50
x2 = round(rgamma(20, 6, .08),2)  # mean 75
x = c(x1,x2);  g = rep(1:2, c(30,20))
t.test(x ~ g)$p.val
[1] 0.0109518
t.obs=t.test(x ~ g)$stat;  t.obs
        t 
-2.669206
```

Boxplots of the two samples are shown below. Nonoverlapping notches, based on a nonparametric test, suggest that population
locations differ. The wider box corresponds to the larger sample.
Shapiro-Wilk tests show that `x2` is not consistent with sampling from a normal population, but the normal null hypothesis is rejected for `x1` with a tiny P-value.

```r
boxplot(x~g, var=TRUE, notch=TRUE, col="skyblue2", pch=10)
```

[image]

We see that the P-value of the Welch t test and the
the P-value of the two-sample test that uses the Welch t
statistic as metric are essentially the same. This suggests
that the two sample means are sufficiently close to normally
distributed not to ruin the P-value of the Welch test.

```r
set.seed(526)
t.prm = replicate(10^5, t.test(x~sample(g))$stat)
mean(abs(t.prm) > abs(t.obs))
[1] 0.00963  # P-value of permutation test
```

The permutation test has the advantage that the exact
permutation distribution could, in principle, be derived
using combinatorial methods. (For example, the most
negative value of the permuted t statistic occurs when the largest 30 of the 50
observations are randomized to the first group.) The simulation procedure generates enough random values from the true permutation distribution of Welch's $T$ to give a useful P-value.

```r
hist(t.prm, prob=TRUE, col="skyblue2", 
     main="Permutation Dist'n of Welch T")
  abline(v=c(t.obs, -t.obs), 
         col="red", lty="dotted", lwd=2)
```

[image]

*Note:* The R code for the permutation test 'steals' the
Welch t statistic (witn `$`-notation) for each permutation of 50 samples into respective groups of 30 and 20. Because `t.test` computes quantities not directly uses for the permutation test, the program runs more slowly than would if optimally programmed.
Other than laziness, the method with `$` ensures that I am
using *exactly* the version of the Welch test implemented in R.)

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen. Thanks for this edit in particular and also for all your edits to improve Q & As on the site.